# Abrir arquivo em Python, em uma pasta diferente (Explorer)

Tags: python, windows, csv, análise-de-dados

Gostaria de saber alguma forma para se abrir um arquivo (exemplo, um .csv para fazer alguma análise de dados) a partir do Windows Explorer. Exemplo:

`arquivo = open('arquivo_1.csv','r')`

mas, com o arquivo 'arquivo_1.csv' proveniente de uma pasta diferente de onde o arquivo .py (por exemplo) estiver. No caso, não sei se o termo é correto, mas seria como importar o arquivo .csv para ser usado no código, sem necessariamente escrever o nome do arquivo explicitamente.

Comment: é só você colocar o path completo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe o meio sem "quase dependências", que é usando os parâmetros, exemplo:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    arquivo = sys.argv[1]
    print(arquivo)
else:
   print('Digite o caminho completo')
```

Então você chamaria assim:

```
C:\Users\new_g>python C:\Users\new_g\Desktop\teste.py c:\foo\bar\baz.txt
```

Usei o `print()` só para ver o caminho, basta trocar pelo seu código.

Claro que é um exemplo bem simples e seria possível criar parâmetros "com nomes", para ser mais intuitivo, mas exigiria muito mais coisas para implementar no script.

Outro meio é usar uma biblioteca que trabalhe com "janelas" (interface gráfica do sistema operacional), um exemplo é a [**tkinter**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) (interface Tcl/Tk).

Antes de responder, o nome geralmente desse tipo de janela para selecionar arquivos no gerenciador, como o Windows Explorer, ou o Finder (do Mac) é (geralmente) *"choose file"*, então um exemplo disso em tkinter seria:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

arquivo = askopenfilename()

print(arquivo)
```

Um detalhe que você pode querer ajustar em qualquer um dos scripts é usar o `with` junto com o open para abrir o arquivo, algo como:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from csv import reader

arquivo = askopenfilename()

try:
    with reader(open(arquivo, 'r')) as read:
        print(read)
except:
    print('Falhou')
```

Mas isso é apenas sugestão.